# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' in xamarin App

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm having an issue with this. I'm trying to generate a list with a number of symbols (needs to be 2 of each). Sometimes works and sometimes throws this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Code:

```
static int[] letras = new int[16];

string[] simbolo = new string[]{"A","B","A","B","C","D","C","D","E","F","E","F","G","H","G","H"};

for (int i = 0; i < letras.Length; i++){
    letras[i] = Convert.ToString(simbolo)[alea.Next(0, simbolo.Length)];
}
```

It's a Xamarin C# application...

Comment: Hint: what do you think the result of `Convert.ToString(simbolo)` is? I suspect you'd be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jon Skeet.

`Convert.ToString(simbolo)` would actually convert the type of simbolo to string, i.e - `System.String[]` not the actual string you intended.

Change your code as below -

```
static int[] letras = new int[16];

string[] simbolo = new string[]{"A","B","A","B","C","D","C","D","E","F","E","F","G","H","G","H"};

for (int i = 0; i < letras.Length; i++){
    letras[i] = string.Join("", simbolo);[alea.Next(0, simbolo.Length)];
}
```